# Python Selenium - Closing all webdrivers

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping a website which has 2 versions at the moment, and when you visit the site you never know which one you are going to get. For this reason I have had to set up two separate files to scrape it.

For the sake of simplicity I have a master file which controls the running of the two files:

```
attempts = 0
while attempts < 10:
    try:
        try:
            runfile('file1.py')
        except SomeException:
            runfile('file2.py')
        break
    except:
        attempts += 1
```

So basically this keeps trying a maximum of 10 times until the correct version of the site meets the correct scraper file.

The problem with this is that the files launch a `webdriver` every time, so I can end up with several empty browsers clogging up the machine. Is there any command which can just close all webdriver instances? I cannot use `driver.quit()` because in the environment of this umbrella script, `driver` is not a recognized variable.

I also cannot use `driver.quit()` at the end of `file1.py` or `file2.py` because when `file1.py` encounters an error, it ceases to run and so the `driver.quit()` command will not be executed. I can't use a `try / except` because then my master file won't understand that there was an error in `file1.py` and thus won't run `file2.py`.

Comment: What do you mean `driver` isn't a recognized variable? You have to store the webdriver object _somewhere_. Why can't you call `.quit()` on that?

Comment: You can use `driver.quit()` in files `file1.py` and `file2.py` at the end (i.e. when the work of the webdriver is done).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar when `file1.py` encounters an error, it ceases to run and so the `driver.quit()` command will not be executed. I can't use a `try` / `except` because then my master file won't understand that there was an error in `file1.py` and thus won't run `file2.py`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. You should add that part in the question; it'll help others to answer your question (seems important to solve the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the exception in individual runners, close the driver and raise a common exception that you then handle in the caller.

In file1.py and file2.py

```
try:
    # routine
except Exception as e:
    driver.quit()
    raise e
```

You can factor this out to the caller by initializing the driver in the caller, and passing the driver instance to functions instead of modules.

Comment: I like that, didn't realise you could manually `raise` an exception. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try..finally block in `runfile`.

```
def runfile(filename):
    driver = ...
    try:
        ...
    finally:
        # close the webdriver
        driver.quit()
```